# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim In_Total As Integer = 0
    Dim Ph_Total As Integer = 0

    Dim Day_In_Total As Integer = 0
    Dim Day_Ph_Total As Integer = 0
    Dim Course_Names1(1) As String

    Qry = "SELECT DISTINCT Course_Name,Course_ID FROM Courses WHERE (Course_ID IN  (SELECT Course_Id FROM Student_Courses_Pref WHERE student_Id IN (SELECT student_Id FROM Student_Info  WHERE Inserted_date >= '" + Now.Month.ToString() + "-1-" + Now.Year.ToString() + "' and Inserted_date <= '" + Now.Date + "' and Branch_Code = '" + BName + "') and Branch_Code = '" + BName + "')) and Branch_Code = '" + BName + "' and Active = 'Y' order by Course_Id"
    str = str + "<br> <br> <center><font face ='Verdana' size='+1'><B><U> Summary Report of " + MonthName(Now.Month()).ToString() + "," + Now.Year.ToString() + "</B></U> <br><br>"
    com.CommandText = Qry
    com.Connection = con
    dr = com.ExecuteReader

    str = str + "<table align='center' style='FONT-FAMILY: Verdana' bgcolor='#336699' width='100%'>"
    str = str + "<tr style='FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: x-small;FONT-FAMILY: Verdana' bgColor='#b9ceee'><td align='center' width='3%'> Date </td>"
    i = 0

    While dr.Read
        str = str + "<td align='Center' colspan='2' width='30%'>" + dr(0).ToString() + "</td>"
        ReDim Preserve Course_Names1(i)
        Course_Names1(i) = dr(1)
        i = i + 1
    End While
    dr.Close()
    str = str + "<td colspan ='2'>Total</td></tr>"
    For i = 0 To Now.Day
        If i = 1 Then
            str = str + "<tr style='FONT-SIZE: x-small;FONT-FAMILY: Verdana' bgColor='#b9ceee'><td>" + i.ToString() + "<sup>st</sup>" + MonthName(Now.Month()).Substring(0, 3) + "</td>"
        ElseIf i = 2 Then
            str = str + "<tr style='FONT-SIZE: x-small;FONT-FAMILY: Verdana' bgColor='#b9ceee'><td>" + i.ToString() + "<sup>nd</sup>" + MonthName(Now.Month()).Substring(0, 3) + "</td>"
        ElseIf i = 3 Then
            str = str + "<tr style='FONT-SIZE: x-small;FONT-FAMILY: Verdana' bgColor='#b9ceee'><td>" + i.ToString() + "<sup>rd</sup>" + MonthName(Now.Month()).Substring(0, 3) + "</td>"
        Else
            str = str + "<tr style='FONT-SIZE: x-small;FONT-FAMILY: Verdana' bgColor='#b9ceee'><td>" + i.ToString() + "<sup>th</sup>" + MonthName(Now.Month()).Substring(0, 3) + "</td>"
        End If
        Qry = ""
        For j = 0 To Course_Names1.Length - 1 'Here i got the error
            Qry = "select count(student_id),enquiry_by from student_info where inserted_date = '" + MonthName(Now.Month).ToString() + " " + i.ToString() + "," + Now.Year.ToString() + "' and student_id in (select student_id from student_courses_pref where branch_code = '" + BName + "' and Course_id = '" + Course_Names1(j).ToString() + "') and branch_code ='" + BName + "' group by Enquiry_By "
            com.CommandText = Qry
            dr = com.ExecuteReader
            While dr.Read()
                If dr.HasRows Then
                    If UCase(dr(1).ToString()) = "I" Then
                        'str = str + "<td width='15%' bgcolor='#ffffff'>" + dr(0).ToString() + "</td><td width='15%' bgcolor='#c2ffc8'></td>"
                        In_Total += dr(0)
                    ElseIf UCase(dr(1).ToString()) = "P" Then
                        'str = str + "<td width='15%'bgcolor='#ffffff'></td><td width='15%' bgcolor='#c2ffc8'>" + dr(0).ToString() + "</td>"
                        Ph_Total += dr(0)
                    End If
                Else
                    'str = str + "<td width='15%' bgcolor='#ffffff'></td><td width='15%' bgcolor='#c2ffc8'></td>"
                End If
            End While
            If In_Total <> 0 Then
                str = str + "<td width='15%' bgcolor='#ffffff'>" + In_Total.ToString() + "</td>"
            Else
                str = str + "<td width='15%' bgcolor='#ffffff'> </td>"
            End If

            If Ph_Total <> 0 Then
                str = str + "<td width='15%' bgcolor='#c2ffc8'>" + Ph_Total.ToString() + "</td>"
            Else
                str = str + "<td width='15%' bgcolor='#c2ffc8'> </td>"
            End If
            dr.Close()
            Day_In_Total += In_Total
            Day_Ph_Total += Ph_Total

            In_Total = 0
            Ph_Total = 0
        Next
        str = str + "<td>" + Day_In_Total.ToString() + "</td><td>" + Day_Ph_Total.ToString() + "</td></tr>"
        Day_In_Total = 0
        Day_Ph_Total = 0
    Next
    str = str + "</tr></table>"
```

Comment: This could either mean that j is null, or Course_Names1 is null, which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Where ist str defined?
Is it initialized with `Dim str as string=""`???

```
str = str + "<br> <br>...
```

Comment: Ya this is string
dim str as String=""